# How to install emerald package on Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management

How can I install the **Emerald** package on **Mint**? I cannot seem to find and install it in the *Synaptic Package Manager*. I think the repository of this package is missing. But I don't know where it is and how to add it to the current list of repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emerald window decorator isn't available in the Ubuntu official repositories(Mint included) anymore, unfortunately, but there are other way to acquire it.

I am not aware of any PPAs for Precise, but building it from source is really straightforward. Here's a basic guide for 12.04:

http://iamfuss.deviantart.com/journal/Install-emerald-for-Ubuntu-12-04-292806813